# Is there a way to embed a React Native simulator in an Electron app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, electron

My friends and I are building an Electron app (a personal project) that helps you build React Native apps. We would love to have a live preview of the React Native app within the Electron app. Is there a way to do this?

I tried seeing if Expo would allow you to do this but seems like there is no documentation.

Comment: Expo Snacks use [Appetize](https://appetize.io) to show emulations. But it's going to cost.

Answer (score 0):

It could be interesting to look at [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) and try to integrate it to electron. It would be lighter to support than an emulator . 
I have not tried yet but it seems that there is a [library](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-native-electron/blob/master/README.md) that provided an extension to react-native-web / electron.

I hope that it will helps you !